# SQL select variables from table-1 and return count for IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table-A

```
color_id- color
1- green
2- blue
3- orange
.
.
55- yellow
```

Table-B

```
person-id, color
1, green
1, blue
2, orange
3, yellow
3, blue
```

There are 55+ colors in table A used by thousands of persons, I need to return count of each color used by each person i.e

it should return result like

```
person_id, green, orange, blue, ......, yellow
1, 1,0,1,0,....0
2,0,1,0,....,0
3,0,0,1,...1
```

The problem is that there are 55+ different color types, they all are saved in Table-A, I can write a select statement and then type all these 55 different variables and get their counts, is their a quick way to select variables from Table-A and then return their count instead of
select person_id, green count(*).......yellow count(*)

I am using SQL server 2014.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you store the color string in two places?  The second table should have `color_id`, not `color`.

Comment: A simple join and group by should handle this just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a Dynamic Pivot here.. since your TableB has the actual color, instead of the color id, you can just pivot the one table..

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',','') + '[' + color + ']' FROM TableA 

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT person_id, ' + @cols + ' FROM TableB PIVOT (COUNT(color) FOR color IN (' + @cols + ')) p'

EXEC (@Sql)
```

Comment: Thanks JamieD77, it worked great, now just one more issue, is their a way to use group by person_id here since it's returning multiple rows for each person_id. Many Thanks!

Comment: did you include another field besides the colors and the personid?

Comment: Here is a sql fiddle.. if you can add your changes i can take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6faf50/1

Comment: it was my mistake, it's working perfectly. Thank you, Thank you, Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
 PIVOT (COUNT(color) 
        FOR color
        IN (green,blue,Orange,yellow)  --<-- just mention all the colors here once
        )p
```